# h2 lucene boost

Tags: lucene, h2

We are trying to use H2 Lucene full text search functionality. It works great. Now we are asked to give weight for specific fields in the H2 (at index creation time, not during search). Say column 1 to have weight of 100 and column 2 would be 50 (as it is less important field). This is same as "field boost" functionality in lucene. Is it possible to do this boost functionality in H2 lucene full text search, during the index creation?

Also i am not sure how we can get the relevancy Lucene score in H2?

Comment: H2 Supports the native or Apache Lucene libraries. While I don't see any quick documentation on field boosts through the H2 Documentation it does support Apache Lucene as the engine--and that engine does. I would investigate that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to change the Lucene support within H2. It's only one class that needs to be changed, the class [FullTextLucene](http://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/fulltext/FullTextLucene.java).

You could then submit a patch to the H2 mailing list, so it get's included in the next version of H2.

Comment: Trying to understand the code now, hope to make some progress soon.